# typedef of char pointers in c++

Tags: c++, typedef

I am trying to learn some subtle differences when using typedef's for pointer to char arrays.
what is the difference in the following statements. Are they same or different?

```
typedef char (*charray)[10];
typedef char* (char_array)[10];
```

Even though these types of typedef's are rarely used nevertheless want to understand it.